# Linux application settings in flutter

Tags: linux, flutter, build

When I finished a desktop aplication with using flutter on Pardus/linux based system, I couldn't find how to set app settings for linux such as app name, icon, verison etc.
How can edit them

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following:

- Figured out where the $app_name binary is located
- Created a *.desktop file with following content:

  ```
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=app_name 
  Exec=/home/$USER/{your_path}/{app_name}/build/linux/debug/./demo_app
  Icon=/home/$USER/.icons/flutter.png
  Comment=Welcome to the flutterverse!
  Categories=Development;
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true;
  ```

You can read more about it over the Flutter official Github:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53229

Comment: Thank for answer but it didn't work actually this [user](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53229#issuecomment-780713943) have same problem

Comment: that's a different thing... you want to customize the window?

Comment: no I only want to customize icon, app name and version. [example image](https://ibb.co/kQhZr82) but it doesnt work

Comment: for example in this video https://youtu.be/3EHNNi9KWoU?t=322 he made a snap app with snap.yaml  but snap is causing problems in other linux based system other than ubuntu. is there any ayternative?